# Network service wired and wi-fi cannot connect

Tags: 16.04

Please help me to fix my case,

I used the ubuntu 16.04, that network services wired and wifi cannot connect. I try to check my cable and that's good. And my campus wifi is good. I try to restart network manager and can't solve.

Any referensi, guide, or solution to fix this.

Comment: 99% of these issues are due to driver not coming with the kernel of older ubuntu and needing to either compile the wifi driver from source or change the kernel but we can't help you since we don't know what driver to recommend since you haven't given use your exact hardware. what is your exact laptop?

Comment: sorry for may late, my laptop is Dell inspiron 14. Or do you want any information from my laptop?? Since I'm still newbie for using linux. Thanks before.

Comment: if you google Dell inspiron 14 you'll see there are nearly a thousand different specific model numbers. still cannot help you.

Comment: Sorry, this is my summary laptop information, can this information help??

-Computer-
Processor  : 2x Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4000 CPU @ 1.10GHz
Memory  : 3841MB (2574MB used)
Operating System  : Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
User Name  : chairul (chairul)
Date/Time  : Sel 25 Jun 2019 06:01:23  WIB
-Display-
Resolution  : 1366x768 pixels
OpenGL Renderer  : Unknown
X11 Vendor  : The X.Org Foundation

Comment: this is still less information than giving the model number, look : `tuf504gd-dm932t` google that see how much information you can get. for example, what the exact model of network card installed is. and what driver it needs. the model number is what I'm asking for.

Comment: Dear @tatsu, this information help, I take from terminal,

System Information
        Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
        Product Name: Inspiron 14-3473
        Version: 1.5.0
        Serial Number: 2P556P2
        UUID: 4C4C4544-0050-3510-8035-B2C04F365032
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: 083B
        Family: Inspiron

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
        Product Name: 0XRFX0
        Version: A00
        Serial Number: .2P556P2.CNWSC0091V006E.

Please, :)